# Unable to get IP address of Raspberry pi to connect via Windows remote connect

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, ethernet, remote, connection

I borrowed the RPI 3B from a friend's friend. hence I don't know the hostname so that I can ping the RPI to know its IP address. Hence I am following this tutorial to get its IP address.

According to the tutorial that I am following to get the IP address, he is using 
`Advanced IP scanner`. So the steps are :

Step 1 : Go to Network and Sharing center

Step 2 : Since I am also connected to my institution wifi, the tutorial asked me to configure the "Internet connection sharing" for my wifi. I changed it to Ethernet by checking the "allow other network users to connect through this computer’s internet connection" option.

Step 3 : Now go the raspberry ethernet network connection(which is my raspberry pi), click on properties and then assign IP address to the raspberry which I did by entering "192.168.137.1" and then the subnet which was automatically filled to "255.255.255.0"

Step 4 : Now open the app Advance IP address scanner and scan the IP address by entering the range "192.168.137.0-192.168.137.244".

Step 5 : Now you can see the IP address along with other devices IP on the screen.

But I am unable to view the IP address of my raspberry PI on the the app. Where am I going wrong. How can I get the IP address of my RPI so that I can connect to it via PUTTY?

**EDIT:**

```
C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar>ping raspberrypi

Pinging raspberrypi.local [fe80::86a0:66d7:ab15:c29%15] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::86a0:66d7:ab15:c29%15: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::86a0:66d7:ab15:c29%15: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::86a0:66d7:ab15:c29%15: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::86a0:66d7:ab15:c29%15: time=1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::86a0:66d7:ab15:c29%15:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

**Update** with info from comments:
I don't have access to the gui, I just got the RPI from friend and then I flashed my sd card and then connected it through ethernet to my computer.

I was talking about clicking on network settings in windows for my ethernet connection. `ethernet connection settings` I was network status -> Network and sharing center and then clicking on my ethernet connection to which RPI was connected.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; these have been moved to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103341/discussion-on-question-by-himanshu-poddar-unable-to-get-ip-address-of-raspberry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I borrowed the RPI 3B from a friend's friend. hence I don't know the
>   hostname so that I can ping the RPI to know its IP address.

Raspberry Pi is a board without any internal storage hence it doesn't matter where you got this. You installed your own operating system (a downloaded image file) on the SD-Card and because of that, you have formated (remove any data on the SD-Card).
In summary, forget it about it's for your friend or someone else.

---

> Step 4: Now open the app Advance IP address scanner and scan the IP
>   address by entering the range "192.168.137.0-192.168.137.244".

The software you have installed just trying all IP address in a range you set, but you have confused about the range of addresses, therefore, you couldn't find who is Raspberry Pi on the LAN.

You just need to ping Raspberry Pi's hostname to get the IP address:

```
ping raspberrypi
```

Also, it will get Raspberry Pi's IPv6 address. So, through one of these commands you can find the IPv4 address:

```
ping raspberrypi -4
```

Or:

```
ping raspberrypi.local
```

Comment: Since I am a beginner, so I thought that what changes to the user my friend made will remain until we don't change it again. I did not know the fact that once you install new OS everything is reset as RPI, does not have any memory of its own

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar As an example, look at an Android smartphone. It has internal storage for the operation system (Android subsystem files) and of course a slot that you can plug an sd-card as external storage. In this case, if you unplug the sd-card, nothing will happen to the operating system because this essential data is in the internal storage (which is not sd-card and is a chip on the smartphone's board). On the other hand, the Raspberry Pi doesn't have any internal storage chip like smartphones. Therefore, you need to put operating system files on a storage to run it. So, what can you do?

Comment: ... You must add a storage for the board. You can't add a storage chip to the Raspberry Pi's board! So, what next? Alright, you must add an sd-card for this problem. Then, you write the operating system file to the sd-card (unlike smartphone) and then plug the sd-card to the Raspberry Pi's sc-card socket/slot. Finally, when you turn it on, the system/operating system files would be read and RUN.

Answer (score -1):

```
ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $7}'
```

I think Raspbian Buster didn't answer to ping, that'as why Raspberry may not appears in IPscanners. On more time, with a VPN the problem is solved.

Comment: You should edit your first answer to improve it with additional suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

Install a VPN for example Hamachi.
First install it on your PC and create a network, then :

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo wget https://www.vpn.net/installers/logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.203-1_armhf.deb    
sudo dpkg -i logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.203-1_armhf.deb
```

then install and join network :

```
sudo hamachi login    
sudo hamachi join my_network
```

*

Another way is to do with OpenVPN, but it's more tricky because need an OpenVPN-server previously installed...

Comment: Installing a Virtual Private Network has really nothing to do with finding an ip address on a local network.

Comment: Sure but is a solution "to connect via Windows remote connect"...

For a pure answer, i could say : "ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $7}'"
But not the solution for a windows-connection-solution...