# Very strange SSH problem with iPhone hotspot

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w, headless

I am newbie with Raspberry and this is my first time using it.

I downloaded Rasbian Buster Lite and flashed it with Etcher. Added `ssh` named file to boot directory and also file named `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Rasp is connecting to iPhone's hotspot fine no problem, but i can not connect to it with Putty.

In `wpa_supplicant.conf` file i have this code:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="name"
    psk="password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Of course real name and real password in real file.

I tried to log in with hosts: `raspberrypi` and `raspberrypi.local`. Not working. Putty says `Unable to open connection to raspberrypi. Host does not exist`.

Also tried `ipconfig /flushdns` which i found from one page, it is not help either.

Comment: Did you get the IP address of the Raspberry Pi by `ping raspberrypi.local` and put the IP to the PuTTY for connecting over SSH protocol? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107323/44221

Comment: A hotspot will give the Pi internet access but does not magically turn the iPhone into a router

Comment: @Milliways That is true. I dig up my old modem and it worked with that. I used 2G mode, 5G does not work with this Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I think it's quite hit & miss connecting via SSH over iPhone hotspots. See this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194842/iphone-is-the-hotspot-isolated-can-you-see-other-devices

Some people have had luck with it, others haven't. I don't know of any official documentation detailing what versions it should/shouldn't work with. If you can, definitely try the same setup with a regular WiFi router.